# I'm having hard time setting up kafka on gke and would like to know the best way of setting it up?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, google-kubernetes-engine

I was trying to use statefulset to deploy the zookeeper and Kafka server in a cluster in gke but the communication between the Kafka and zookeeper fails with an error message in logs. I'd like to know what would be the easiest way to setup a Kafka in kubernetes.

I've tried the following configurations and I see that the Kafka fails to communicate with zookeeper but I am not sure why? I know that I may need a headless service because the communication is being handled by Kafka and zookeeper themselves.

**For Zookeeper**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: zookeeper
  ports:
  - port: 2181
    targetPort: client
    name: zk-port
  - port: 2888
    targetPort: leader
    name: zk-leader
  - port: 3888
    targetPort: election
    name: zk-election
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
  serviceName: zookeeper
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zk-pod
          image: zookeeper:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: client
              containerPort: 2181
            - name: leader
              containerPort: 2888
            - name: election
              containerPort: 3888
          env:
            - name: ZOO_MY_ID
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: ZOO_TICK_TIME
              value: "2000"
            - name: ZOO_INIT_LIMIT
              value: "5"
            - name: ZOO_SYNC_LIMIT
              value: "2"
            - name: ZOO_SERVERS
              value: zookeeper:2888:3888
```

**For Kafka**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  serviceName: kafka-svc
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kafka
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9092
            name: client
        env:
          - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
            value: zookeeper:2181
          - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
            value: kafka.default.svc.cluster.local:9092
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-svc
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: kafka
  ports:
  - port: 9092
    targetPort: client
    name: kfk-port
---
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: kafka-pdb
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  minAvailable: 2
```

I'd like to be able to send messages to a topic and to be able to read them back. I've been using [kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat) to test the connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of limitation that specified in [Official Kubernetes Documentation about StateFulsets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#limitations), that

> - StatefulSets currently require a Headless Service to be responsible    for the network identity of the Pods. You are responsible for creating this Service.

So, as you mentioned, you need [Headless Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) and you can just easily add  headless service yaml to top of your configuration similar to below for your both StatefulSets:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
  labels:
    app: zookeeper
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 2181 
    name: someport
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: zookeeper
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: how can i communicate with the services? with the headless services the ClusterIP or external IP isn't defined.

Comment: Headless service *with selector* modifies the DNS configuration to return A records (addresses) that point directly to the Pods backing the Service. So, you need to specify service name to communicate. Check also if endpoints are created via `kubectl get ep`. Check this out https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#with-selectors

Comment: I've added the headless service however I'm still not able to access other pods from within a pod.  I'm able to see the endpoint being created but no access is to pod. When i try to telnet other container using ```telnet zookeeper-2.zookeeper-service.kafka-ns.svc.cluster.local 2181``` it just says ```bad address 'zookeeper-2.zookeeper-service.kafka-ns.svc.cluster.local'```

Comment: If you want to have separate DNS names for each pods, you have to create subdomain service, and use it on pods template. Check this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods

Answer (score 0):

I have been following the official guide from Google Click to Deploy. It proves very beneficial for me. Here is the link that you can follow to setup Kafka cluster over GKE. This github repository is officially maintained by Google Cloud.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/tree/master/k8s/kafka

Other simpe approach is to deploy via Google Cloud Console.

1. https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace
2. Search for kafka cluster (with replication)
3. Click on Configure
4. Fill out all necessary details and it will configure Kafka cluster for you will all internal communication enabled. I have removed my cluster name for privacy.

[image]